# Why does reduced row echelon form give the linear combination of columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am sure I am missing something obvious here, but when one finds the reduced row echelon form of a matrix, each column of the RREF gives the decomposition of the corresponding column in the original matrix as a linear combination of the original columns.

I am struggling to see how row operations on the matrix result in this being the case…

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to view this that makes sense to me…

Suppose for simplicity we have a rank 2 matrix with 3 columns. And the third column is $a$ times the first column plus $b$ times the second.

I will write this as

$A= (\textbf{c}_1, c_2, ac_1 + bc_2)$

(Apologies for the bad formatting. I am using my mobile device but will reformat when on a computer).

Now if we do row operations, this still clearly holds that $c_3 = ac_1+ bc_2$

But, after we obtain RREF, by looking at where the leading ones are it is clear that we obtain a in the first entry of column 3, b in the second entry. This we get our decomposition.

Comment: This was the conjecture made in the query - "Each column of the RREF gives the decomposition of the corresponding column in the original matrix as a linear combination of the original columns."

Answer (score -1):

Basically we find the rref(A) [row-reduced echelon form of A] to find the rank of the matrix A or importantly to solve a set of linear equations

$ A x = b$

Note that solution of this system does not change when you perform elementary row operations.

However, consider the example below to understand how is 'rref(A)' related to the original columns of $A$.

Let us take

$ A = \left[ \matrix{1 & 2 & 3 \cr 1 & 2 & 3 \cr 1 & 2 & 3 \cr} \right].$

Then it is easy to check that

$
B = \mbox{rref}(A) = \left[ \matrix{1 & 2 & 3 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 \cr} \right].$

It is clear that the columns of $B$ (the echelon form of $A$) cannot be
deduced as linear combinations of the columns of $A$.

However, the rows of $B$ (obviously) are obtained as linear combinations of the rows of the original matrix $A$.

I have elaborated all this in my text-book on Numerical Linear Algebra.

Comment: This does not address the question.